# While accessing SQL using php, why enter a variable like '".$q."' instead of just $q or "$q"

Tags: php, sql, variables, quotations

The statement in question is:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
```

Where q is an integer. Why type it like that when you can just type it like

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $q";
```

because it's an integer, it shouldn't require the quotes right, or even if it did require quotes, why not just one pair. What's the significance of `'".$var_name."'`?

Comment: Or you could prepare it. You wouldn't need to concat variables in query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't require any `''`, but in combination with `*real_escape_string`, to make it effective, you need these single quotes.

Because if the user input would be: `1 OR 1 = 1`, then the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 1 OR 1 = 1
```

what would select the whole table.

But if you use single quotes with `*real_escape_string` and the user input is `1' OR '1' = '1`, then the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '1\' OR \'1\' = \'1'
```

what won't select the whole table, but just one id.

tl;dr: It is not needed, but it makes your code safe against sql injection.

Comment: +1, another approach without prepare would be `intval` or some freaky technique.

Comment: Yes, I sometimes use `(int)` what looks a bit cleaner. But I prefer too many single quotes than not enough ;-)

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping me out, but I'm still a beginner and I still don't quite understand it. Would it be alright if I could get an explanation a little more detailed?

Comment: @user2624376 I'd consider to read this article in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: I just did and I still don't understand all of it. 
How would 
WHERE id = 1 or 1 = 1 
display the whole table? 
Wouldn't it have to be WHERE id = 1 OR 2 OR 3...?

And how would quotes really prevent this? 
It'd say 
WHERE '". 1 OR 1 = 1 ."'? 
How would this prevent anything? I'm really new to this and I've been learning off of the w3schools website and there's pretty much no mention about this.

Comment: `1=1` is a condition which is always true, that's why it selects the whole table

Comment: @bwoebi I spent some time reading up on mysql_real_escape_string and I've fairly understood teh concept now. But I still don't understand why the quotes are necessary. 
Why can't we just use 
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $q"; 
in conjunction with mysql_real_escape_string($q)?

Wouldn't this be just as safe as '".$q."'?

Comment: My only guess is that the quotes are added because in the situation like 1 OR 1 = 1, the quotes tell the system to treat that as a string instead of as an sql command. I'm not sure how true that is.

Comment: @user2624376 your guess is correct. The `'` are delimiting a string and mysql_real_escape_string will (also) escape the single quotes from the input, so that one cannot write sql commands, but just a string.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the double quotes are there because concatenation is being used; the following two statements are equivalent:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '" . $q . "'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '$q'";
```

That said, integers don't need to be quoted in SQL, so this would be fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $q";
```

If `$q` wasn't sanitized yet and you don't wish to use prepared statements, you could use `sprintf()` in the following manner:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = %d", (int)$q);
```

In the case of strings I would go for prepared statements or make sure the variable is properly escaped (in case the deprecrated `mysql_` functions are still used):

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($q));
```